# Working with Streams wrapped in Options

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers, scala-cats

I am working with some nested `Stream`s and would like to use the for comprehension syntax with them:

```
def handleNestedStream(as : Stream[A]) : Stream[(A, B)] = {
    a <- as
    b <- makeBs(a)
} yield (a, b)
```

However, the `makeBs` function returns an `Option[Stream[B]]`.  I would like the `Option` to be unwrapped automatically. In addition, I would like the entire function to return `None` if `makeBs` fails. So the new function would look something like this:

```
def makeBs(a : A) : Option[Stream[B]] = { ... }

def handleNestedStream(as : Stream[A]) : Option[Stream[(A, B)]] = {
    a <- as
    b <- makeBs(a)
} yield (a, b)
```

The only change is the type of the function.

How can I accomplish something like this? Can `StreamingT` from cats or `StreamT` from scalaz help here?

Some of the types are flexible. `makeBs` can be made to return `Stream[Option[B]]` instead of `Option[Stream[B]]` if that would make things simpler.

I need to use the scala standard lib `Stream` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine that implementation

```
import scalaz._
import std.option._
import syntax.std.option._

type StreamO[X] = StreamT[Option,X]

def makeBs(a : A) : StreamO[B] = ???

def handleNestedStream(as : Stream[A]) : StreamO[(A, B)] = for {
  a <- StreamT fromStream as.some
  b <- makeBs(a)
} yield (a, b)
```

Suppose now

```
import syntax.monad._
type A = Int
type B = String
def makeBs(a : A) = for (x <- a.point[StreamO] if x % 2 == 1) yield x.toString * x

handleNestedStream(1 to 5 toStream).toStream
```

will be evaluated as

> Some(Stream((1,1), (3,333), (5,55555)))

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to use `traverseM` from `scalaz`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def handleNestedStream(as : Stream[A]) : Option[Stream[(A, B)]] = 
  as.traverseM(a => makeBs(a).map(_.map(a ->)))
```

The principal signature of `traverseM` is `traverseM(fa: F[A])(f: A => G[F[B]]): G[F[B]]` (`F` should have instances of `Traverse` and `Bind`, and `G` should have an instance of `Applicative`). In this case `F` is `Stream`, `G` is `Option`, and `B` in the signature is `(A, B)` from your example.

So if you call `traverseM` on `Stream[A]`, and want to get back `Option[Stream[(A, B)]]`, you should pass it a function `A => Option[Stream[(A, B)]]` – this is naturally `makeBs`, followed by a deep map that makes `(A, B)` pairs.

The functions with suffix `M` (`filterM`, `traverseM`, `foldLeftM`, etc.) are generally quite useful when you want to combine several different contexts, but without the boilerplate of monad transformers.